# when i press back button while standing on firebase Authentication UI mt app doesn't exit instead it shows an activity with hello world text

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using firebase Authentication UI for sign in and sing up of my users. when my app starts the first screen which appears in front is firebase Authentication UI when I press back button while standing on Firebase Authentication UI the firebase Authentication UI gets disappear and an empty activity with hello text world is shown then app exits on pressing back button again. while the app was supposed to exit when I press back button while standing on Firebase Authentication UI because it is the first screen which is visible to my user when he opens the app . The first image is the image which is visible to my user when he opens the app while the second image is the mage which becomes visible to my user when he presses back button while standing on the first screen of my app.[image: This is the first dcreen which appers when user opens the app]
[image: This screen becomes visible to user when he press the back button while standing on Firebase Authentication UI although app was suppose to exit if user presses back button while standing on Firebase Authentication UI because it is the first screen of app]
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.anonymous.ghar_ka_khana;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.ErrorCodes;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private String signinthrough;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference databaserefrence;
    private ChildEventListener databaselistener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaserefrence= database.getReference().child("Users");


        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            // not signed in
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                            .setAvailableProviders(
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()))
                            .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any existing Activity at all with the 'Hello World' UI?

Comment: No there is no existing Activity

Comment: try my answer and let me if it works

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury your answer didnt work . still facing same problem

Answer (score 3):

Go to fun onActivityResult in your (FirebaseUIActivity or MainActivity) class, if the response is null that means the user pressed back button, then you either finish() or createSignInIntent()

```
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           //...
           //...
        }else{
            if (response == null) {
                // back button is pressed
                finish()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should overwrite the onBackPressed(),this method will run when press back button.

Answer (score 0):

in the `onBackPressed()` stub, write the following code

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);     
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

or use `System.exit(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Reading your answer makes me think you are a troll. It really makes me lose hope in humanity. So please make your sentences as short as you can write.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how  you implemented onActivityResult in MainActivity?

When Firebase UI sign in screen is visible , your actions are calling onActivityResult because of the SignInIntentBuilder. You may try as below in onActivityResult.

```
IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     //Signed In
} else {
//Check here if response is null or other ErrorCodes are received. take actions accordingly. 
    if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
            finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: There  is no function named getErrorCode() in IdpResponse class

Comment: I think you tried to mention `response.getError().getErrorCode()`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In the onActivityResult:

```
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
        }
        else {
            // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
            // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
            // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
            // ...
            if (response==null){
                //The user has pressed the back button
                finish();
            }else{
                //Sign in failed due to some other reason
            }
        }
    }
```